# Bayesian optimization with Keras tuner for time series

Tags: keras, time-series

***Goal***: trying to use walk-forward validation strategy with keras tuner for time series when training a neural network (mainly LSTM and/or CNN).

Did anyone find a direct way of doing this?

One possible way I can think of is:

- implementing a custom 'objective' function, e.g. 'mean squared error' using walk-forward validations trategy
- this custom function could be passed via the 'objective' input parameter in the tuner (be it RandomSearch, BayesianOptimization, Hyperband...)
- when calling tuner.search, we pass the train & validation data, to be used in the walk-forward custom function

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no question here. Can you clarify it, please?

Comment: Already added the explicit question. Nevertheless, I think that is not a reason for giving a downvote on an interesting and necessary topic

Answer (score 0):

I finally came out with a way to implement bayesian hyperparameter optimization for a time series neural network model using walk-forward validation. You can find a gist with the code [here](https://gist.github.com/GermanCM/1943a0dc1eac04f848c6fe9b16947ac4)

I used some helper functions for the walk-forward validation from this [Jason Brownlee book](https://machinelearningmastery.com/deep-learning-for-time-series-forecasting/)

It is basically as follows:

- original time series data:
  [image]
- define a function to convert your time series dataset into a supervised dataset format, another one for the train-test split (ordered in time as done in sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit)

[image]

- define your evaluation metric, root mean squared error in this case
- we also add a differencing function, in case we want to make our time series stationary (by differencing, we can reduce trend and/or stationality)
- define the walk-forward validation functions (*walk_forward_validation and repeat_evaluate*)
- define the keras tuner bayesian optimizer, based on a *build_model* function wich contains the LSTM network in this case with the hidden layers *units* and the *learning rate* as optimizable hyperparameters
- define the *model_fit* function which will be used in the walk-forward training and evaluation step

[image]

- lastly, find the evaluation metric value and std
  [image]

To keep in mind: this is a proof-of-concept example about how to use keras tuner for time series using walk-forward validation. Further analysis could be done to improve forecasts.